# How do I set platform-wide data conversion behavior in EclipseLink?

Tags: eclipselink

We are finding issues (and reporting them) in EclipseLink's `InformixPlatform` class--the class responsible for adapting the Informix database to the requirements of the EclipseLink innards.

We have a couple of type conversion issues.  For example, Informix supports two opaque literals (`t` and `f`--not the characters, but actual literals) as native `boolean` values.  It appears that perhaps EclipseLink is trying to use `SMALLINT` instead as the database type.

Short of a lot of procedural code inside a `SessionCustomizer`, I cannot find a good place to correct or improve such global conversion behavior.

Where is the best place to register this *global* take-a-value-from-the-database-and-convert-it-to-a-Java-object behavior?  [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961655/jpa-eclipselink-type-handling-without-repeated-converter-annotations/7130761#7130761) seem to indicate that this is impossible, but I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: Well, for my purposes, I overrode `DatabasePlatform#appendBoolean(Boolean, Writer)`, which, when the `shouldBindLiterals()` method returns `false`, is called when a `boolean` literal needs to be written out to SQL.  I found that the default implementation of this method simply outputs either `0` or `1`.  In my case, I overrode it to output either `t` or `f` in keeping with [the Informix documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_1400.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your own conversion manager class 
(extend `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager`).

and override the method `convertObjectToBoolean()`.

To enable the usage of your own conversion manager instance in eclipselink, use a `SessionCustomizer` and invoke `session.getPlatform().setConversionManager()`

However, when looking at the source code of this method it seems that the support of the `t` and `f` literals is already implemented (at least in eclipselink 2.3.3).
 But maybe there's a bug?
It's may be worth debugging this method while your application is running to really see what's going on there.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the `ConversionManager`.  That strictly speaking answered my question, though I've since discovered that the problem I was facing was in `DatabasePlatform#appendBoolean()` when `shouldBindLiterals()` is `false`.  There is a definite bug in there, as `1` and `0` are hardcoded and written straight out to SQL by default.  This breaks Informix.  Since you answered the question as asked I'll award you the answer.  Thanks.